# android send notifications in the future

Tags: android, android-notifications, notificationmanager

I'm thinking of the best way to do this.

I have a set of id's and times. Each id contains more than one time (in the future).  Users can select for which id's they would like to get notified.

I was able to use Notification manager and broadcast a notification at a future time. The problem is the times will be updated everyday for a id, so the notification manager should be able to look for changes in times and update itself (only for the id's the users subscribes to).

Should I write a service that runs in the background and sends notification by constantly checking aganist the times ? or is there a better way to do this ?

eg id's and times

> id = 1, times = 10/15/2015 10:00, 10/15/2015 23:00
>
> id = 2, times = 10/15/2015 12:00. 10/16/2015 19:00

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of case, use [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) to schedule a task everyday. Using `Service` to schedule a task may drains the power consumption and sometimes it gets killed by Android system to retain memory resources, because of `Service` itself is in idle state if no thread running on it.

To [schedule a task using AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html), you can do the following action:

```
alarmMgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
    // INTERVAL_DAY = schedule it everyday
    AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, alarmIntent);
```

Comment: I'm not creating a repeating alarm, because it happens at different times and it may not even trigger on some of the days.

Comment: @Jayaram, But you can cancel it by using `cancel()` method and change/re-schedule it programmatically.